# Why linear congruential generator is called random number generator?

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, random, philosophy, congruence-relations

As far my understanding [linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) is used to produce pseudo random number. But the algorithm requires four parameters like,

```
def lcg(modulus, a, c, seed):
    while True:
        seed = (a * seed + c) % modulus
        yield seed
```

In that case to get a true pseudo random number we cannot provide same values of params, then why it is called random generator? if I really need to provide random (seeds, a, c, m) tuples than it raises the same philosophical problem, Is it possible to produce random number? Could anyone describe why its called random generator algorithm?

Comment: an algorithm cant produce a truly random number. What algorithms like these do is produce a series of numbers that pass all the statistical tests for randomness

Comment: @XRBtoTheMOON well (and I'm sorry this is pedantic) they don't pass *all* of the tests... for instance it is periodic with a very large period.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen pedantry is good for math! Thanks for pointing out my error

Comment: In practice, the initial seed can be drawn from the clock at runtime, although it is helpful to set it to a fixed value for reproducibility.  $a,c$ and $m$ are constants defined as part of the implementation. Although it is indeed deterministic, the idea is that it should be very hard for a naive onlooker to tell that, i.e. to detect any dependency between the sequential numbers or deviation from the uniform distribution. This is vaguely what we mean by 'passing statistical tests'.

Comment: Of course you can see the implementation in front of you and so you can backsolve to predict the next number from the current one, so you know it is actually completely dependent. This goes along with the notion of *cryptographically secure* RNGs. Say you don't know what $a,c,m$ are but you know it's an LCG and you have a stream of numbers from the generator in front of you. Could you figure out how to predict it? Turns out it's not too hard for an LCG (so they are not considered secure) but there are other generators that are more difficult to reverse engineer.

Comment: Note by naive observer I mean someone who is a good statistician who understands how to do some standard tests for correlation and distribution fit, but not someone who knows (or has a strong suspicion) that there is some specific deterministic algorithm going on behind the scene.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen thanks for the points, btw could you refer any hard to reverse popular algo beside lcg?

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan A standard algorithm that is higher quality than LCG (i.e. passes more stringent statistical tests) is the Mersenne twister, but it is not secure either in the sense that it can be reverse engineered. For information on the secure varieties: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator